# Multiple Web Applications with Different Default Pages from one folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications, web-deployment

I am looking to deploy a new ASP.NET web application under IIS which will be used by multiple customers all requiring a different skin.  However one of the requirements is that this is only deployed on the web server in one physical folder (e.g. C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebApplication).

I was planning on running multiple virtual directories all pointing to this location and from this multiple Application Pools (this gives me a separate Application State Object for each application)

The problem I have is i need a way of the users hitting different default pages depending on the client base they belong to demonstrated below:

Client 1 
URL: https://www.mydomain.com/Client1Application 
Default Page: Client1Default.aspx (this can be skinned for Client 1's requirements)

Client 2 
URL: https://www.mydomain.com/Client2Application 
Default Page: Client2Default.aspx (this can be skinned for Client 2's requirements)

Is there a way I can easily achieve this in IIS without having to get the client to include the page name in their URL?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Regards,  
Stuart Ferguson

Comment: Do these customers log in? If so, then they should have some form of identifier that you can use to determine who it is (like their provider key, username, etc.). Using these details, you could create a method that selects a particular theme stored in a format you choose (.txt, .htm, .css, etc.). This way, your clients would all have unique skins whilst only using one page.

Comment: @MightyLampshade

The question above is relating to the login page that the user hits having a different skin depending on the virtual application they hit.